# Why isn't log4j2 generating a log file?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I've been tasked with upgrading a large service type java program (not written by me, first exposure to it) that has a large collection of open source libraries.  I'm upgrading to log4j2, it previously had log4j, but I don't know if it ever worked correctly.

I'm not getting a log file at all.  This is in a local development environment using NetBeans 8. I have the log4j-api and log4j-core 2.9.0 files in my classpath. My log4j2.xml file in the project root is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="FileAppender" fileName="DistEngine.log" immediateFlush="true" append="false" >
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

The class logging variable is (yes, the class name is Main, and it extends a parent class):

```
private static final Logger MAINLOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
```

The first line in the main() method of this starting class is:

```
MAINLOGGER.info("entering listener main");
```

I'm not getting a DistEngine.log file in my project root, nor any logging from log4j2 to stdout.  I'm not getting the log4j2 message stating that it can't find the config file.

The config file, class variable and log call are all copied from another program in this collection where the logging works correctly.

I am getting some stdout logging from some of the open source classes, primarily in the com.sun.enterprise.ee.cms.impl.jxta and com.sun.enterprise.ee.cms.impl.jxtamgmt namespaces.

I have a feeling that the open source logging may be conflicting with log4j2 since the other program I copied the code from works fine.

Thanks.

EDIT: more resolution detail:
One of the open source library jar files (jgroups) contained a log4j2.xml file with valid settings.  This config file was used instead of mine, since the project was configured with the lib jars in the classpath before the custom sources.  I only found this out after setting the log4j2.debug property you suggested.

This jgroups config file didn't result in a log4j2 error, but it also didn't generate a log file that I could find.

My solution was to put the custom source folder before the lib jars in the classpath  and it worked.  Without turning this into a classpath order thread, it seems to me custom should come first regardless of this issue, but it appears that the netbeans default is library jars first, then custom.

Comment: What? Jgroups jar contains a log4j2.xml file? THAT’S HORRIBLE! This should be reported as a bug with the jgroup maintainers! This forces you to always ensure the jgroups jar is loaded last or their configuration overrides yours... What were they thinking?

Comment: I was thinking maybe my predecessor put it in their jar for some reason, but I just downloaded the jgroups version that's in my project (3.6.0 Final) from their repository and the log4j2.xml file is there.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t see anything wrong with the configuration file. I suspect that the reason there’s no log file is that Log4j2 didn’t see the configuration file.

By default Log4j2 looks for the configuration file in the classpath. That’s the first thing to check. Does netbeans include the project root in the classpath?

You can also specify the path to the configuration file with system property `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`.
See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location

You can further troubleshoot the configuration by setting system property `log4j2.debug`. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting

(Also, make sure you’re using the latest version of Log4j2.)

Comment: Short Answer: Yes, a classpath issue!  Thanks, longer answer at end of my original post for others who may encounter this.

Comment: thanks! please note that `log4j.configurationFile` is legacy property name and we should use `log4j2.configurationFile` instead